# C# inheritance and Object reference

Tags: c#, inheritance

I am new to C# and trying to figure out how inheritance works. I'm getting the following error. Why must the parent parameters be static?

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0120  An object reference is required for the non-static field,
>   method, or property 'Rectangle.name'  PurrS PATH\Sign.cs  15  Active

Parent:

```
namespace PurrS.Maps
{
public class Rectangle
{
    protected string name;
    protected int id;
    protected float a;
    protected float b;
    protected float c;
    protected float d;
    protected int posX;
    protected int posY;
    //A----B
    //|    | 
    //C----D

    public Rectangle(string name, int id, float a, float b, float c, float d, int posX, int posY)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
        this.d = d;
    }

}
}
```

Child:

```
namespace PurrS.Maps
{

public class Sign : Rectangle
{
    string message;

    public Sign(string message) 
        : base(name, id, a, b, c, d, posX, posY) { //This is where it fails.
        this.message = message;

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are seeing stems from the fact that `Rectangle` has a single constructor - the only way to create an instance of `Rectangle` is to pass it your 8 parameters.

When you create a `Sign` that inherits from `Rectangle` - because it *is* a `Rectangle` - it needs to be able to call its `Rectangle` constructor to be able to successfully construct itself.

Therefore, it needs all the parameters available to call a constructor on `Rectangle` (you have only one), at the time that its constructor is called.

You can ask for the parameters in `Sign`, or hardcode them in the `Sign` constructor:

```
 public Sign(string message, string name, int id, float a, float b, float c, float d, int posX, int posY) 
     :base(name,id,a,b,c,d,posX,poxY)

 public Sign(string message) : base("a name", 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 10)
```

for example.

Answer (score 2):

You must either pass the parameters from a constructor with some more arguments

```
public Sign(string name, int id, float a, float b, float c, float d, int posX, int posY, string message)
                : base(name, id, a, b, c, d, posX, posY)
            { //This is where it fails.
                this.message = message;

            }
```

or provide some default fixed values:

```
        public Sign(string message)
            : base("foo", 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        { //This is where it fails.
            this.message = message;

        }
```

Comment: And here I thought the parameters would automagically be passed on to the parent class. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to expand on this:

```
public Sign(string message) 
    : base(name, id, a, b, c, d, posX, posY) { //This is where it fails.
    this.message = message;
}
```

To pass the parameters to the base class as follows:

```
public Sign(string message, string name, int id, etc...) 
    : base(name, id, a, b, c, d, posX, posY) { 
    this.message = message;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance means that you child class (the Sign class) will have all of the fields and methods that are in the parent class. Therefore, you can say

```
public Sign(string name, int id, float a, float b, float c, float d, int posX, int posY)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
        this.d = d;
    }
```

And not have to declare any of the fields that you are using because they are inherited from the parent class.